# Change checkbox image when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input

I have a basic form with images instead of checkboxes (but act as if).
In order to be more consistent, I want the image to be changed when a user clicks it.

For exemple, when you click on the first icon (Blackjack), it will change from this > [image] to this > [image]

I've tried to do so in JQuery but I think I lack some knowledge. Can you help me fix my script?

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/x0baboc6/

**form.php**

```
<style>
input[type=checkbox]{
  display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="recap.php">
  <p>
    Cliquez sur les icônes des jeux que vous souhaitez:<br>
    <p>

      <label for="blackjack"><img src="img/blackjack.jpg" alt=""></label></p>
      <INPUT id="blackjack" type="checkbox" value="Blackjack" name="game[]">    

<p>
      <label for="chuckaluck"><img src="img/chuckaluck.jpg" alt=""></label></p>
      <INPUT id="chuckaluck" type="checkbox" value="Chuck a Luck" name="game[]">

<p>
      <label for="roulette"><img src="img/roulette.jpg" alt=""></label></p>
      <INPUT id="roulette" type="checkbox" value="Roulette" name="game[]">

<p>
      <label for="stud"><img src="img/stud.jpg" alt=""></label></p>
      <INPUT id="stud" type="checkbox" value="Stud Poker" name="game[]">

<p>
      <label for="holdem"><img src="img/holdem.jpg" alt=""></label></p>
      <INPUT id="holdem" type="checkbox" value="Holdem Poker" name="game[]">

<p>
      <label for="boule"><img src="img/boule.jpg" alt=""></label></p> 
      <INPUT id="boule" type="checkbox" value="La Boule" name="game[]">

    <input type="button" value="Retour en arrière" onClick="self.history.back();">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Poursuivre">
</p>
</form>

<script>
$("#blackjack").click( function(){
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) $('#blackjack').attr('src','img/blackjack.gif');
    }
});;
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#blackjack")` is a checkbox. Your CSS states : `input[type=checkbox]{  display: none}`, so checkboxes are hidden. Your javascript can never be triggered.

Comment: @JeremyThille a hack method would be to trigger the img element instead of checkbox. I think it's possible.

Comment: @JeremyThille it is wrong, the "for" attribute works and replace the click on the checkbox [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84cggj5q/1/)

Comment: Really? Wow, I didn't know this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not directly clicking on the input you can't use click. What you click on however is the label. The label then changes the input value. So instead of click change it to .. you guessed it, `.change()`

The next step is to change the image. The problem here is that you changed the src attribute of the input instead of the img element... so first we need to get the img element and change the src.

```js
$("#blackjack").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        $(this).prev().find('img').attr('src', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6dkP.gif');
    else
       $(this).prev().find('img').attr('src', 'http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg');
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="recap.php">
    <p>Cliquez sur les icônes des jeux que vous souhaitez:
        <br>
        <p>
            <label for="blackjack">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg" alt="">
            </label>
        </p>
        <INPUT id="blackjack" type="checkbox" value="Blackjack" />
</form>
```

Alternatively you can use `$('[for='+this.id+'] img')` for the selector and change the attribute. I suggest something in the style below. With this you don't have to create a handler for every image you will add.

```js
$("form input[type=checkbox]").change(function(e) {
  var state = $(this).is(':checked');
  $('form [for=' + this.id + '] img').attr('src', function() {
    return state ? $(this).data('checked') : $(this).data('unchecked');
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="recap.php">
  <p>Cliquez sur les icônes des jeux que vous souhaitez:
    <br>
    <p>
      <label for="blackjack">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg" data-checked='https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6dkP.gif' data-unchecked='http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg' alt="">
      </label>
    </p>
    <INPUT id="blackjack" type="checkbox" value="Blackjack" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```js
$("img").click( function(){
    if( $(this).attr('data-checked') == "false" ){
       $(this)
           .attr('src','https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6dkP.gif')
           .attr('data-checked', 'true');
    } else {
        $(this)
           .attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg')
           .attr('data-checked', 'false');
    }
        
});
```

```css
img{
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg" data-checked="false" />
```

The trick is to store the "checked" state in a custom attribute (here 'data-checked')

Answer (score 0):

you have to put an id to the picture, like this:

```
 <label for="blackjack"><img  id="test" src="http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg" alt=""/></label></p>
```

in this case "test"

then in the javascript put this:

```
$("#blackjack").click( function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
             $('#test').attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/AvPEx4i.jpg');
        }else{
          $('#test').attr('src','http://i.imgur.com/kfMWC91.jpg');
        }
});
```

here the example http://jsfiddle.net/x0baboc6/3/

edit, to uncheck just put the else in the function.

Comment: And how do you uncheck?